# How to find failed facts from json rule engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, rule-engine, json-rules-engine

I am new to the rules engine and I am trying to create a rules engine in javascript.

I have the following rule and Passing one parameter as the wrong input, how to find which argument (fact) is mismatched (not the rule).

```
  engine.addRule({
    conditions: {
      all: [{
        fact: 'score',
        operator: 'greaterThanInclusive',
        value: 200
      }, {
        fact: 'players',
        operator: 'equal',
        value: 10
      }]
    },
    event: { 
        type: 'success',
    }
})

let fact = {
   score: 150,
   players: 10
}
```

It will fail the rule. How do I know which fact cause the failure of rule?

Answer (score 0):

We gives a property event which will fired when rules match . If rules match the length of events going to be greater than 0.

Example:

```
const { events } = await engine.run(facts);

if (events.length > 0) {
  return true
}
```

In the case of failure of rule events length going to be zero.